# Error sending stream data from Flask Python

Tags: python, flask

The following Python will pass each word from 'words' through SSE every 1 second, but it didn't work correctly. I see that the data: 'word' is waiting for each other, and after the for loop finishes, all of them are sent together in one batch through SSE.
What's the issue?
Thank you very much

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, session
import time
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='')

app.secret_key = '123456789'

def event_stream(texts):
    for word in texts:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "data: {}\n\n".format(word + " ")
    yield "data: {}\n\n".format("endresponse")


@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def handle_message():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form["message"]
        session['message'] = message
        return ""

@app.route("/stream", methods=['GET'])
def stream_route():
    message = session.get('message')
    words = message.split()
            
    return response(event_stream(words), mimetype='text/event-stream')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation only shows the server-side code.
If you call the endpoint that delivers the stream with the browser, it waits until the connection is closed and then interprets the data.
However, if you add the client-side implementation, the partial data is available when it is received. The connection is reestablished as long as the client terminates it.

The following example shows you a possible implementation based on your code.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    session
)
import random, time 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/')
def handle_message():
    prompt = request.form.get('prompt', '').strip()
    if prompt:
        session['prompt'] = prompt
        return ''
    return '', 400

@app.route('/stream')
def sse():
    def event_stream(words):
        for word in words: 
            time.sleep(random.random())
            yield f'data: {word}\n\n'
        yield f'data: eof\n\n'

    text = session.get('prompt', '')
    words = text.split()
    return event_stream(words), { 'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream' }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SSE</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        output {
            display: block;
            padding: 0.5rem;
            white-space: pre;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
            width: 100vw;
        }
        output.in {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        input[name="prompt"] {
            width: calc(100vw - 0.75rem - 8px);
            height: 1.5rem;
            padding: 0 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
            margin: .64rem 4px .64rem 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="cmdln" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="prompt" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {

            const listen = (elem) => {
                const source = new EventSource('/stream');
                source.onmessage = (event) => {
                    if (event.data === 'eof') {
                        source.close();
                    } else {
                        elem.textContent += `${event.data} `;
                    }
                };
            };

            const form = document.querySelector('form[name=cmdln]');
            form.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const formData = new FormData(this);
                if (formData.get('prompt').trim() !== '') {
                    
                    const elemIn = document.createElement('output');
                    elemIn.textContent = formData.get('prompt').trim();
                    elemIn.classList.add('in');
                    document.body.appendChild(elemIn);

                    const r = await fetch('/', {
                        method: 'POST', 
                        body: formData
                    });
                    if (r.ok) {
                        const elemOut = document.createElement('output');
                        elemOut.classList.add('out');
                        document.body.appendChild(elemOut);

                        listen(elemOut);
                    }
                }
            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have run your code, but it didn't work as expected. I tried a prompt with 20 words, i had to wait 20 seconds before all of 'data: word' displayed. I tested it on Chrome

Comment: I'm sorry that my example doesn't work for you as expected. I tested it in several browsers and the words appear on the screen one by one. Since it also works for me in Chrome, I can't tell you why the problem occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: If i run my code or your code offline on PC, it works, but if i create a python app from Cpanel/Setup Python App and uploaded app.py + index.html to the python app folder, it did not work (all datas still sent once, not stream)

Comment: For some reason the server is buffering the streaming. You can try to set the `Cache-Control` to `no-cache` and `X-Accel-Buffering` to `no` in addition to the Content-Type. It may be that the problem can be solved in this way. But I have no idea about server configuration.